# How to inherit types from a component to react-router-dom functions?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Say I need to move from page "/new-post" to "/display". "/display" can recieve props of an interface called SomeStuffProps

```
interface SomeStuffProps {
  stuff: string,
  moreStuff: string
}
```

And "/new-post" have the "stuff" and "moreStuff" for "/display" to work. 
If say I import useHistory and then have the history push to "/display",

```
const stuff = "..."

history.push("/display", state<unknown>); // state<SomeStuffProps>
```

I can have a variable with type of SomeStuffProps before the push. But then, that's only me telling myself what to fill the unknown state or "any" type, and not actually referring the SomeStuffProps from the parent component. What is the best solution to this approach?

Comment: while initializing state you can do `..... useState<SomeStuffProps>(...)`

Comment: I think that you can put the generic on the `push`?  Like `history.push<SomeStuffProps>("/display", state);`

Comment: @LindaPaiste there's no generic support on the function call, but even if that's possible, it does not references to the parent component..

Answer (score 0):

probably not ideal, but i would go with something like this

```
type PageTypes = {
    "/display": SomeStuffProps,
   ... or ...
    "/display": React.ComponentType<typeof DisplayPage>
}
```

and use it like
`history.push("/display", state<PageTypes["/display"]>)`